# Floated li in ul, ul with overflow:auto produces vertical scroll bars

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a `<ul>` with several floated `<li>`'s in it. I did my standard css `overflow:auto;` to clear the float and have the `<ul>` match the size of the children. This works great in the webkit browsers, but in firefox it produces a vertical scrollbar. I solved the problem by using `overflow: hidden;`, but I'm curious if anyone knows why `overflow:auto;` produces this behavior in `<ul>` elements. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you matched the size of children, this means you have set the height/width of `<ul>`, So if there is no adequate height then vertical scrollbar may come. This behaviour can be different depending upon the browser interpretation of differet margins, paddings, defaults etc.

Comment: overflow:auto; and overflow:hidden; on the parent element causes it to automatically size to its children, no height was set on the ul element.

Comment: I think I dont know the exact explanation, but when stuck in similar situations i keep some wiggle room in sense of heights and widths

Answer (score 0):

There is no overflow: none. The default is "visible". Which undoes the float-containment you wanted with overflow: auto.

If you're setting overflow,then do not set a height on the ul at all. Setting a height on an element with overflow is really asking for the children to either get cut off (overflow: hidden) or force a scrollbar (auto). Not setting the dimensions on the parent mean "auto" has no reason to create any scrollbars in the first place.

Without seeing any code, likely the difference between browsers is just font rendering. Perhaps your Firefox diplays the text inside the li's just a hair bigger. Making the li's bigger. Making them need to overflow out of their fixed-height container.

Though if that's the case and for some reason you really need to set a height on an overflow-controlling parent, try setting that height in em's instead. It can grow a bit with the text then, so long as text doesn't wrap to a new line.

You can also use any of the many other float-containment codes out there if this one is picky with heights.

Comment: I did not set the ul height; when you set overflow to hidden or auto it has the ul height equal the height of its children. When I chose overflow: hidden; it got rid of the scroll bar, but for overflow: auto; it showed a scroll bar. This is peculiar behavior because without setting the ul's height, overflow auto show just cause the ul element to be the complete size of its children and not create a vertical scroll.

Comment: As to your font rendering comment, shouldn't that not play a role? The ul should automatically resize to whatever size it renders the children

Comment: Sorry but I had to assume you were setting a height on the ul (you posted very little code and we get to guess what's going on) because that is what causes scrollbars to appear on overflow:auto elements (dimensions set who are smaller than total size of children). You're right about the fonts if height is auto but if a larger font can make larger children and something restricts the parent's dimensions then you'll see it. In any case, if you post more code another possibility may turn up.